# Black Screen After Splash Screen iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, simulator

Working on a senior project, and my app started to load only a black screen after the splash screen recently.  I am not using storyboards.  I've been searching for a solution to this problem, but cannot seem to adapt other solutions to my project.  My [github] (https://github.com/cleif/Hastings/tree/Fixed) has the latest build here.  Below is code from my AppDelegate.h & .m files.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IIViewDeckController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "AboutViewController.h"
#import "AthleticsViewController.h"
#import "BroncoBoardViewController.h"
#import "ContactsTableViewController.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIViewController *menuViewController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIViewController *rootViewController;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize menuViewController = _menuViewController;

- (IIViewDeckController*) initializeMainViewControllers {

UIViewController *menuViewController      = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *rootViewController      = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

IIViewDeckController* deckController      = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController]
                                                                                    leftViewController:menuViewController];

return deckController;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

IIViewDeckController* deckController    = [self initializeMainViewControllers];

self.menuViewController                 = deckController.leftController;
self.rootViewController                 = deckController.centerController;

self.window.rootViewController          = deckController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

@end
```

Any Suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen in the simulator only? Because I've seen this as well, sending the app to the background and back to the foreground seems to bring back the app.

Comment: Your `self.window` seems to be nil. Try adding `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got your code and added below line to - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions and it is working fine now

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
```

so your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method  must be like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

IIViewDeckController* deckController    = [self initializeMainViewControllers];

self.menuViewController                 = deckController.leftController;
self.rootViewController                 = deckController.centerController;

self.window.rootViewController          = deckController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: You most Welcome. no need to say thanks. i likes to help others.